# Flyway Migrations with Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, migration, flyway, oracle12c

I'm looking to get Flyway migrations setup with Oracle 12C, however running the 'flyway baseline' I received the following error on schema_table creation.

```
Message    : ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

The end-goal here with this setup is to get a CI and CD process that can create an Oracle Database (with DBCA) then run flyway migrate to migrate the database to the latest version.

With that in mind, how can I get passed this issue? Do i need to create the scheme and Tablespace configuration outside of Flyway before I do anything?.

Edit: Moudiz has suggested ALTER USER  quota 100M on USERS, whilst that does get me passed the issue. I'd be more interested in a solution in the area of dbca/flyway configuration. Any extra 'tweak' script i need to run for deployment is not ideal.

Comment: would this help you ? run it as dba user ALTER USER <user> quota 100M on <tablespace name>;

Comment: It does, i've ran into this solution previously. But is this really required? I had tested this on Oracle 11g XE previously and didn't experience this error at all. Is this a new thing with Oracle 12c? Is there something in the DBCA configuration template that can help me avoid this error?

Comment: maybe in 11g already had tablespace I am not sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this statement should help you.

```
 ALTER USER <user> quota 100M on USERS
```